# How do I rotate 1 of 2 external displays to portrait, in OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook, displayport

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro Retina, and two Dell U2414 24" displays. Each display is connected directly to the MacBook by DisplayPort.

When I try to rotate one of the displays to portrait, using the "Rotation" menu in the Display Control Panel, all 3 of the screens rotate by 90 (or 270).

Help?